# Is Rust's `Result<T,E>` better than C++'s try/catch?

Tags: c++

After moving from C++ to Rust for a while, I noticed how `Result<T,E>` is useful. It forced me to handle errors better than `try/catch`, which lead me to think that we'd have something like it in C++20, as `std::optional`, but I found nothing.

I found a simple implementation here: https://github.com/oktal/result

Example of usage:

```
Result<Request, Error> parseRequest(const std::string& payload) {
    if (payload.size() > 512) return Err(Error(Kind::TooLong, "Request exceeded maximum allowed size (512 bytes)"));

    Request request;
    return Ok(request);
}

std::string payload = receivePayload();
auto request = parseRequest(payload).expect("Failed to parse request");
```

I plan to add this in my project, but I don't like the idea of relying on a non standard library for my project, even though it's a simple `.h` with no dependencies.

Are there real benefits form using a custom `Result<T,E>` than doing try/catch?

An exception interrupts the execution of the code, but returning a `Result` also interrupts it. However, an exception can interrupt a chain of function calls. So:

```
int f1() {//...}
int f2() {//...; f1()}
int f3() {//...; f2()}
```

If we call `f3()` then an exception that is thrown at `f1` can be handled by the code that called `f3`. With `Result`, I'd be forced to handle 'exceptions' of `f1` on `f2`, and then handle exceptions of `f2` on `f3`, etc (suppose all these functions return a `Result<T,E>`. This looks better because it forces me to handle more specific errors. We all know that in the end people will simply write a big try catch for all exceptions, like: `try {f3()} catch (std::exception e) {//just print it}`

So, should I consider using a `Result` for a more modern error handling or should I rely on try catch?

If Rust dont even have try/catch then `Result` might be powerful

Comment: Rusts `Result` is used when errors are expected and recoverable and, if an error does not occur, the result must be used.  Exceptions (in C++ and other languages) are used when errors are unexpected or unusual, potentially unrecoverable, and prevent a result being produced.   Their purposes are completely different, so identifying which is "better" depends on use case.

Comment: IMO you should not view this technique *instead* of exceptions but use it *as well as* exceptions. They largely address different types of error and have different uses - though there is overlap.

Comment: The C++ equivalent would be `std::variant<T,E>`. This is not comparable to exceptions because they do not address the same problem.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Wouldn't the C++ equivalent be `std::experimental::expected<T.E>` ?

Comment: @MSalters I was not aware of that. But I also don't think its an actual language feature yet. I can't find anything on it on cppreference or the latest draft. I also couldn't find a TR including it.

Comment: @Peter The Rust documentation describes `Result` as doing a subset of what exceptions do.

> Rust doesn’t have exceptions. Instead, it has the type Result<T, E> for recoverable errors and the panic! macro that stops execution when the program encounters an unrecoverable error. ... Most languages don’t distinguish between these two kinds of errors and handle both in the same way

So, `Result<T, E>` very much *does* do a lot of what exceptions do. Why not compare the two things based on how they are 90% similar instead of acting like they are 'completely different'?

Comment: `std::expected<T,E>` is in C++23.